# React - Background image even if i got 3 components rendering?

Tags: reactjs, background, components

Im trying to change the background image of my application depending on API response, but the first thing i need to figure out is how can i have an image background covering the whole application when i have 3 components rendering header, main and footer?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share that piece of code? so we can have a clear idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Main = () => {

return(
<div className='background'> //set background image
//import components here

</div>

)

}
```

I am sure you are importing them to a Main/Prent component. Add background image to the div in Parent and import components inside that div.